# Stop twitter bootstrap css being responsive after a certain screen width - ie. < 1000px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-2

Im using the bootstrap 2.3.2 css framework to set out the interface for a web app. Im using the responsive version of the framework.

The application dosnt need to be mobile + tablet responsive, but im using the responsive version so the interfaces scaled horizontally on wider monitors (a large part of the UI is tabular data so users with bigger screens will appreciate being able to use the full width of their screens).

Is there a way i can use the responsive features of bootstrap, but stop them being responsive after a certin point - ie. at < 1000px  the interface would no longer be responsive (a user could still make it larger, but not smaller)

Essentially i want to stop the `span` and `offset` elements that make up the grid scaling after `<1000px`

Comment: Just remove all the media queries that affect less than 1000px viewports... This should be obvious

Comment: Have you considered using [mixins](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-less) in less? you can build your own version of bootstrap this way, by altering the variables that control the responsiveness (via) breakpoints in one place rather than walking through the style manually

Comment: If you are interested in this, http://getbootstrap.com has a way to edit the variables and build directly from the website: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables

Answer (score 9):

I have modified Bootstrap to not include the responsive features for devices under 1000px.

This example should demonstrate this: http://floating-wildwood-8562.herokuapp.com/examples/grid.html

You can use this modified responsive bootstrap css file [here](http://floating-wildwood-8562.herokuapp.com/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css).

This required two changes to Bootstrap's LESS files and a rebuild of the framework.
[Shown here](https://github.com/sfarthin/bootstrap-custom-responsive/commit/094dcae8e0eb8c3e68d724425e95d1ddca88d7de#diff-729ee0122ecee5021c37c976f872c9b9) and [here](https://github.com/sfarthin/bootstrap-custom-responsive/commit/094dcae8e0eb8c3e68d724425e95d1ddca88d7de#diff-64fe81002058aa10d328af429427161e)

---

You may also decide to add this to your css:

```
html, body {
  min-width: 1000px;
}
```

This way the window will be forced to be at least 1000px.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't used bootstrap, but it must have a css, u should see how u called your main wrapper and at the end of it add.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #main_wrap {
        width:1000px;
    }
}
```

I re read your question and this is what you have to look for example, you keep the main wrap at 100% width, but theres some elements like image wrappers text wrappers, etc... so... look for all of them in the css (not media queries) and place a min-width... example

```
/* ------ NORMAL FORMATTING Examples */

#img_wrapper {
     min-width:300px;
}
#text_wrapper {
     min-width:400px;
}
#logo_wrapper {
     min-width:100px;
}

/* ------ Media Queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
        #main_wrap {
            width:100% /* ----> This keeps 100% for responsive */
        }
    }
```

why this U don't have to query them when they achieve to that min-size they wont resize anymore, they will stay that size even. if the screen keeps resizing.
I hope this helped

If you wanna query them then don't put a min-size just give them a exact width

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
            #main_wrap {
                width:100% /* ----> This keeps 100% for responsive */
            }
                #img_wrapper {
                    width:300px;
                }
                #text_wrapper {
                   width:400px;
                }
                #logo_wrapper {
                   width:100px;
                  }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but although this stops the wrapper going below `1000px` it dosnt stop the individual elements which are controlled by the `spans` getting smaller

Comment: Ok I added stuff, read it carefully, this might work then... enjoy anything re write... ;)